# Silex and two mysql connections

Tags: php, doctrine, yaml, silex

//EDIT
It was configuration mistake. Please ignore

For some reason I can't setup silex to use two mysql connections.

Here's my configuration

```
database:
    dbs.options:
        site: 
            driver: pdo_mysql
            host: x.x.x.x
            dbname: db1
            user: user
            password: pass
        regular:
            driver: pdo_mysql
            host: x.x.x.x
            dbname: db2 
            user: user
            password: pass
```

When I try to execute query for example

```
$this->app['dbs']['site']->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM users);
```

I get an error saying `Identifier "site" is not defined.`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the right syntax for using multiple connections:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'dbs.options' => array (
        'mysql_read' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'      => 'mysql_read.someplace.tld',
            'dbname'    => 'my_database',
            'user'      => 'my_username',
            'password'  => 'my_password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
        ),
        'mysql_write' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'      => 'mysql_write.someplace.tld',
            'dbname'    => 'my_database',
            'user'      => 'my_username',
            'password'  => 'my_password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Source: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html